# String Invoke Issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker, invoke

I am using a backgroundworker and I think there is a cross thread thing.. But I cant solve it.

my code is here

```
  private void bgworkerGameLoad_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var arg = e.Argument.ToString();
        var liste = webHelper.ShowGame("http://www.abx.com/" + arg);

        txtHowToPlay.Invoke(new Action(() => txtHowToPlay.Text = String.Format("Oyun Bilgi: {0}", liste[0])));

        txtInfo.Invoke(new Action(() => txtInfo.Text = String.Format("Nasıl Oynanır: {0}", liste[1])));

       bgworkerGameLoad.ReportProgress(0,liste[2]);

    }

   private void bgworkerGameLoad_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {


        if (FlashPlayerActive)
            UnLoad();
        string url="";
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                url= e.UserState.ToString();
            Thread.Sleep(2);
        }));

        axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = url;

        LoadFlash();

        pbWaitForChannelLoading.Visible = false;
        axShockwaveFlash1.Play();
    }
```

the problem is that I cant get the   e.UserState.ToString() for my shocwaveplayer. I used a local string variable but its the same result.

it is occured targetofaninvocation exception in program.cs

```
     Application.Run(new FrmMain());;
```

but that code is in frmMain.cs

this is detail of the exception

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled
>     Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>     Source=mscorlib
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
>          at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
>          at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>          at XXX.Program.Main() in c:\Users..............\Program.cs:line 23
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>     InnerException: System.NullReferenceException
>          Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>          Source=System.Windows.Forms
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
>               at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
>               at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method)
>               at XXX.FrmMain.bgworkerGameLoad_RunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) in c:\Users..........\FrmMain.cs:line 332
>               at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnRunWorkerCompleted(RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
>               at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.AsyncOperationCompleted(Object arg)
>          InnerException:

what is my mistake? I tried to use delegate but its the same..

Comment: BgWorker runs on seperate thread than UI.So you cant access UI controls like txtHowToPlay in bg_DoWork method.

Comment: @JonSkeet, its         Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                {
                    xx = e.UserState.ToString();
                Thread.Sleep(2);
            }));

Comment: @usercr, hey its not a problem. it works.. but the problem i cant access the string variable even i tried to use method invoker

Comment: You need to look at the exception's InnerException to see what went wrong.  It is easier to diagnose by using Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions so the debugger stops when the exception is thrown.

In general you are doing it wrong, there isn't anything that your DoWork event handler does that takes time so you are simply not ahead by making your code hard to write and diagnose.  If you find yourself just needing to write Begin/Invoke then you know you are doing it wrong ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem..

I hadnt added axShockwaveFlash1 to my form before set values..

in LoadFlash function, it was

```
    public void LoadFlash()
    {

        axShockwaveFlash1 = new AxShockwaveFlash();
        axShockwaveFlash1.BeginInit();
        axShockwaveFlash1.Location = new Point(14, 196);
        axShockwaveFlash1.Name = "Test Movie";
        axShockwaveFlash1.TabIndex = 0;
        axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = liste[2];
        axShockwaveFlash1.EmbedMovie = true;
        axShockwaveFlash1.AutoSize = true;
        axShockwaveFlash1.Size = new Size(640, 480);

        axShockwaveFlash1.Visible = true;
        axShockwaveFlash1.EndInit();
        splitContainerControl.Panel2.Controls.Add(axShockwaveFlash1);
        FlashPlayerActive = true;

    }
```

but i changed this code like

```
    public void LoadFlash()
    {

        axShockwaveFlash1 = new AxShockwaveFlash();

      splitContainerControl.Panel2.Controls.Add(axShockwaveFlash1);

        axShockwaveFlash1.BeginInit();
        axShockwaveFlash1.Location = new Point(14, 196);
     ...
```

it works..

if found the solution here

http://forum.fusioncharts.com/topic/2424-how-to-resolve-invalidactivexstateexception-while-loading-chart/#entry8855

thanx

Comment: In that case you didn't give us the right information when we asked you which was line 332. It sounds like line 332 was *actually* `axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = url` - which again probably shouldn't be done in a background thread either.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem is as simple as `e.UserState` being null. You don't even need to use `Invoke` to get at `UserState` - you'll see the same problem if you just have:

```
if (FlashPlayerActive)
    UnLoad();
string url = e.UserState.ToString();
Thread.Sleep(2); // This is generally a bad idea anyway, btw...
```

Where are you setting the `UserState`? I suspect you're not setting it anywhere, so it's still null, which is why you're getting an exception.

Comment: e.UserState is not null, in ..DoWork I wrote this code        bgworkerGameLoad.ReportProgress(0,liste[2]);
and it doesnt work what you wrote..

Comment: @ertan2002: "and it doesnt work what you wrote" gives us very little useful information. What happens? If `e.UserState` is not null, what is the value of `url` after executing the middle statement in the code I posted? You must be clearer, otherwise we can't help you.